# Does Devise support two differently scoped models with the same name in two different engines?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, rails-engines

I'm using two different rails mountable engines in a single app. Both engines are using devise and both have a 'User' model that's scoped. E.g.

```
module Module1
    class User < ActiveRecord::Base
        devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
            :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
    end
end

module Module2
    class User < ActiveRecord::Base
        devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
            :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
    end
end
```

I've set the Devise config scopes in both engines

```
Devise.setup do |config|
    config.scoped_views = true
    config.default_scope = :module1_user
    config.router_name = :module1
    config.parent_controller = 'Module1::ApplicationController'
end
```

and

```
Devise.setup do |config|
    config.scoped_views = true
    config.default_scope = :module2_user
    config.router_name = :module2
    config.parent_controller = 'Module2::ApplicationController'
end
```

also there is no conflict in the tables as they're correctly scoped:

```
module1_users
module2_users
```

Also, the routes seem to be in order - running rake routes shows that there are Devise routes in each engine.

I have overridden the Devise views in one of the engines - module2, but not in module1

The problem is, the engines seem to conflict - signing in to one engine signs in to both engines and signing out signs out of both. The user is always redirected to the module2 sign in page. A couple questions:

1. Is there a setting that forces Devise to generate scoped versions of it's helper functions? e.g. There's an `:authenticate_<my_model>!` function. Is there a setting that would produce: `:authenticate_<my_module>_<my_model>!` function? (Inspecting my scoped controllers shows that the helper functions are not scoped by default - e.g. in rails console `Module1::MyController.new.methods` yields only `:authenticate_user!`, not `:authenticate_module1_user!`)
2. Does Devise support this kind of set up? Two differently scoped models with the same name in two different engines?

Comment: could i ask what you are trying to achieve? Devise lets you setup multiple authentication models with no conflicts

Comment: I'm hoping to build a couple rails engines for internal tools that will have a distinct set of functions and log ins. I'd like to be able to host them on the same server and add/remove them at will. I was hoping to let each have a 'User' model in a different scope and still use devise. I'd like to avoid prefixing the 'User' model with the module name (e.g. 'Admin_User') just because it seems unnecessary if the model's already scoped.

Comment: But then aren't you reinventing devise so to speak as opposed to using its core functionality? Couldn't everyone just be a user defined by a user type? A simple flag in the db? Don't know if that would fit your needs but would save defining scopes and making something what seems relatively simple into something rather complicated

Comment: That's a good point.. My goal was to keep it modular so that I could eventually pull the engines apart and put them on their own without having to do too much work. Hosting them together was more of a short term thing. I'll think about this a little more though because you're right, there's probably a scheme where I could leverage one user class that has different permissions based on the user type.